# image link in html not correct in FireFox

Tags: html, firefox

I am working on a ASP.NET website and in a panel I show help descriptions.
These help descriptions are created by someone else in HTML.
Mostly its a paragraph and in one occassion there is an image.
Here it is going strang with FF.

the HTML is simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title></title>

</head>
<body style="font: 14px arial;">
    <p>Make reservations on EMTU assets</p>
    <img src="9901_files/image002.png" alt="" />
</body>
</html>
```

The page file tree is like:

- root / requestdescriptions / 9901_files

The HTML file is in 'RequestDescriptions' and is called "9901.HTM".
The image is in the '9901_files' folder.

In IE and Chrome the image is shown. So no problem there.

Then there is FireFox.

If I look at the webconsole in FF, I notice that the image is not found as FF tries to get it from 'root/9901_files'. Why is it not looking in 'root/requestdescriptions/9901_files'???

rg.
Eric

Answer (score 0):

Probably firefox is starting in the root when looking for an image. You could try adding ./ before the "file_src", so firefox starts in the same directory.

What if it says the following for your image code:

```
<img src="./9901_files/image002.png" alt="" />
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't change anything.

Comment: Can you show an online example where it is not working? The strange thing is the browser just gets the html_code. What does the URL look like in the browser bar?

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

Thanks to Rober Deiman, I found that the calling link had a backslash instead of a forwardslash in the link.
Apparently FireFox doesn't correct it like Chrome and IE.